# android how to alert array values

Tags: java, android, arrays, alert

i have the following code

```
StarIOPort port = null;
port = StarIOPort.getPort("BT:", "mini", 10000, ctx);
```

How can I alert port values?

I don't know if port is an array or something else.

Comment: By 'alert', do you mean that you want to create an alert dialog box containing the values of port?

Comment: I'm not really sure what to say here, other than to figure out how to represent a StarIOPort as a string (toString?) and then put it in to an alert dialog

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html